# `Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true })` vs `exports.__esModule = true`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, umd

I figured that this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true })
```

Should give the same result as this:

```js
exports.__esModule = true
```

But all UMD bundle generators I've seen have used the first option. Is there a reason?

Comment: The difference is that the first one creates a *non-enumerable* property. I guess that’s the main reason.

Comment: @FelixKling ah, that makes sense

Comment: @Bergi this question is not a duplicate. The question was specifically about the choice to use `Object.defineProperty` for ES Modules, a very specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty()` has different defaults than just assigning the property normally.  Specifically, the following attributes all default to `false` if you don't specify them:

```
configurable
enumerable
writable
```

So, `Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true })` will have the same value, but will not be configurable, enumerable or writable whereas `exports.__esModule = true` will have all those attributes default to `true`.

You can read about this level of detail on `Object.definePropert()` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

> But all UMD bundle generators I've seen have used the first option. Is there a reason?

Presumably, the designers of those tools want that property configured so it can't be changed (writable) or deleted (configurable) or enumerated.

Comment: Huh, I always thought writable is true by default... TIL.